# PowerShell Output Filenames of a Specific Extension to a Text File

Tags: windows, powershell

Currently, I'm using the following command to output filenames to a text file:

```
( Get-ChildItem -File ).BaseName | Out-File "Track List.txt" -Encoding utf8
```

How can I limit the filenames to a specific extension, e.g., .mp3?

Comment: ... by using the parameter `-Filter` for the cmdlet [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) !?

Comment: Example please?

Comment: Wow. How rude! :-/ Read the help topic!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -Filter paramater accepts wildecards - ? for any single character, and * for zero or more matches

```
( Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.mp3).BaseName | Out-File "Track List.txt" -Encoding utf8
```

See the Powershell documentaiton on [-Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.2) and [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2) for more information
[wildcards]:

Comment: Excellent answer. I used it right away, thank you!